# I need multiline type writing effect with multiple loops i.e. after finishing the all lines, start again in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, animation

I used "animation-iteration-count: infinite" but it needs to be used of every line separately. I need it to be applied on all lines combined. My code uses separate CSS class for every line which is quite annoying. I need one single class to be applied on whole text no matter how many line or paragraphs there are. Below is my code.

```css
.css-typing p {
  font-family: "Courier";
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 200em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-animation: type 2s steps(40, end);
  animation: type 4s steps(40, end);
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.css-typing p:nth-child(2) {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: type 2s steps(40, end);
  animation: type2 4s steps(40, end);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-delay: 5s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.css-typing p:nth-child(3) {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: type 5s steps(40, end);
  animation: type3 4s steps(40, end);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
  animation-delay: 10s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes type {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes type {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
}

span {
  animation: blink 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes type2 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes type2 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes type3 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes type3 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="css-typing">
  <p>
    Typed <br> text 1
  </p>
  <p>
    Typed text 2
  </p>
  <p>
    Typed text 3
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What i need is after all lines are written, they get removed and start again.  I used this "animation-iteration-count: infinite;" but it is applied on single line, not on whole frame. Run the given above code, you will understand.

Comment: do you just want to add a class for all/every paragraphs?

Comment: No, its already adding. This is the problem, it iterates every paragraph separately. I need once all paragraphs are written, they all disappear and then typing starts again. Which means one css class controls all paras. No need to add multiple classes.

Answer (score 0):

I think CSS animation is not the way to go.

If possible, you can actually write the characters to the browser from JS.

From the top of my head you should have:

- Text in JS array. each element represents a line.
- `setInterval` that calls a function that pops each time a line
- another `setInterval` or `setTimeout` that will put each letter there, using `substr` and keep an index where you are at any given time.

If you don't want to code, google for [codepen typing effect](https://googl.com/#q=codepen+typing+effect), I'm sure you will find something you will like.